# Arrange elements horizontally or vertically wrapped in a div

Tags: css

I am trying to write generic css selectors which will arrange any elements wrapped inside a div as vertically or horizontally.  I do not have control on the elements which will be placed inside outer div.

For example : In below snippet, div (id=one), div(id=two) and button (id = three) should be displayed as horizontally arranged list of elements.

```
<div class="arrange-horizontally">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <button id="three"></button>
</div>
```

Similarly, I need to write another css selector to arrange elements in vertical fashion.

```
<div class="arrange-vertically">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <button id="three"></button>
</div>
```

I tried with display:table-row (displays these elements horizontally).
display:table-cell does not arrange elements vertically. 
In fact; I am looking for better approach first and then solution.

This is the css I am using to get the desired effect. One more change, I am making sure either of the vertical or horizontal styled div is enclosed in a div with .table
Below is just one of the example and there could be more such combinations.

```
<div class="table>
    <div class="arrange-vertically">
       <div>
             <button>1stverticallyPlacedElement</button>
   </div>
       <div class="arrange-horizontally">
             <div>some comp1</div>
             <div>some comp1</div>
             <div>some comp2</div>
       </div>

      <button id="three">This is 3rd element in vertical block</button>
    </div>
</div>


    .table {
        display: table;
     }

     .arrange-horizontally {
         overflow-x:scroll;
     }

     .arrange-horizontally > * {
         display:table-cell;

     }

     .arrange-vertically {
     }

     .arrange-vertically > * {
         display:table-row; 
     }
```

Issues with this -

- No scroll bars are coming when I try to push lot of elements in the
  horizontal/vertically styled div.
- From sample code above, "some comp1" element's width is changed as per  "1stverticallyPlacedElement"'s width. This is definitely an issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
.arrange-horizontally > * {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.arrange-vertically > * {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This is working for nested blocks as well. http://jsfiddle.net/eX35D/ I will try some more use cases.

Comment: how would we get scroll bars? Now when we try pushing lott of elements in div with arrange-horizontally, it is pushing elements in the next row. JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/eX35D/4/

Comment: If you don't want the horizontal bar to break into new lines you can use white-space: nowrap.

http://jsfiddle.net/eX35D/5/

Comment: Btw: Not sure if I understood you correctly. If your intention is to create scrollbars at the bottom of the page then the jsfiddle I posted will suffice. If you want to scoll the content of the arrange-horizontally-block alone then all you have to do is add "overflow: auto;" right underneath the white-space-declaration.

Comment: yes, my intention was to get horizontal scroll for the div only (arrange-horizontally block) and overflow:auto did work.

Comment: If my answer did solve your issue then please mark it as such.

Comment: yeah sure. One more use case which does not work with display:inline-block is zooming/resizing of browser window.  That is the reason I am trying out display:table.

Answer (score 6):

Use `inline-block` to display the div elements horizontally. For the vertical example, see the fiddle, it's very simple.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qu66W/6/

HTML:

```
<div id="horizontal">
    <div>First one</div>
    <div>Second one</div>
    <div>Third one</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.horizontal{
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid green
}

.horizontal  *{

    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.vertical {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue
}

.vertical  > *{
    display :block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using float? They all align themselves horizontally using float.
Or try looking up display Inline.
For vertical, use 
 tags and then horizontal align with top.