# I want to understand how to put 2 (and more) images on top of each other

Tags: html, css, image

So I made a page that just has 2 images with 2 texts next to them. I don't understand how to make them on top of each other instead of next to each other

[Example of how I want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAavs.png)

And this is the code.

```
  <head>
  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Dog and Cat</title>

    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
      .box {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .box .text {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        margin: 0 auto;
        left: 100%;
        right: 0;
        top: 30%;
        text-align: center;
        width: 60%;
      }
      img {
        margin: 0;
        height: 200px;
        padding: 5%;
        border-radius: 10%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543466835-00a7907e9de1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8ZG9nfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
        alt="dog"
      />
      <div class="text">
        <h2></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519052537078-e6302a4968d4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTR8fGNhdHxlbnwwfDB8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
        alt="cat"
      />
      <div class="text">
        <h2>cat</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrange elements horizontally or vertically wrapped in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504817/arrange-elements-horizontally-or-vertically-wrapped-in-a-div)

Comment: No, not really. I used display: inline-block; for it. It works for wrapping but it's not really what I want. I want it to just be below each other regardless of the viewport size

Comment: Remove the display inline-block and allow the div to be block by default and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Everything can be solved using flex

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Dog and Cat</title>
    <style>
      .box {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }
      img {
        margin: 0;
        height: 200px;
        padding: 5%;
        border-radius: 10%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543466835-00a7907e9de1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8ZG9nfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
        alt="dog"
      />
      <div class="text">
        <h2>dog</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519052537078-e6302a4968d4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTR8fGNhdHxlbnwwfDB8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
        alt="cat"
      />
      <div class="text">
        <h2>cat</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a job for flexbox or CSS grid. Let's use flexbox for simplicity.

```css
 

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

}

img {
    margin: 0;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 30px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="box">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543466835-00a7907e9de1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8ZG9nfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
        alt="dog"
      />
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Dog</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519052537078-e6302a4968d4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTR8fGNhdHxlbnwwfDB8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
        alt="cat"
      />
      <div class="text">
        <h2>cat</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to make the boxes `block` than `inline-block`. This can be observed from the answer I have marked your question a duplicate for.

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
      }
      .box {
        position: relative;
        display: block
      }
      .box .text {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        margin: 0 auto;
        left: 100%;
        right: 0;
        top: 30%;
        text-align: left;
        width: 60%;
      }
      img {
        margin: 0;
        height: 200px;
        padding: 5%;
        border-radius: 10%;
      }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="box">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543466835-00a7907e9de1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8ZG9nfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
        alt="dog"
      />
      <div class="text">
        <h2>rrrrr</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519052537078-e6302a4968d4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTR8fGNhdHxlbnwwfDB8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
        alt="cat"
      />
      <div class="text">
        <h2>cat</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS grid or flex box !!

```css
.box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

}
```